# Vagrant Set IP Syntax Error

Tags: vagrant

I seem to be getting an error when trying to set a static IP on a vagrant box. Within my vagrant file I have this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

config.vm.box = "box-cutter/centos67"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5”

end
```

I seem to be getting an error when running Vagrant UP:

here is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
message is reproduced below for convenience:

```
/Vagrantfile:4: unterminated string meets end of file
/Vagrantfile:4: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

If I remove the `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5”` line the box will boot up fine.

Am I missing something, I have copied this from the Vagrant website

Thanks for your help

---

After changing the quotes to be the same i now get this error:

```
/Vagrantfile:4: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
config.vm.network “private_network”, ip: “192.168.50.5”

Vagrantfile:4: syntax error, unexpected tFLOAT, expecting '('
config.vm.network “private_network”, ip: “192.168.50.5”
```

Comment: One of those quotes is not like the others.

Comment: I didn't even see that, i've changed it but now get this error:

Comment: Now _both_ of the quotes are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael Hampton - putting the correct quotes in

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

```
config.vm.box = "box-cutter/centos67"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"

end
```

TextEdit on Mac was putting **“** instead of **"**